# Sending An Emoji Via AJAX Post With UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, utf-8

I'm trying to send data through AJAX to a PHP file to then upload to my database using SQL. I've already altered my table to allow UTF-8 to be inserted. When I insert using a form it works fine but when using AJAX to send data it won't send it.

For example, I'm trying to send some text and an emoji to a PHP file which then uploads to my database.

I've already got `<meta charset="utf-8">` at the top of my page and even added `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");` to the page and PHP file as I've seen some other posts mention that but it hasn't worked.

Here is the AJAX function:

`$detail = $('#post').text(); //Gets text from div`

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'edit.php',
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
    data: {detail: $detail},
    datatype: 'html',
    success: function() {
        console.log($detail);
}});
```

The `$detail` is simply the value from a div and all the edit file simply does is `UPDATE` the table.

When I `console.log` the data it comes back with text and an emoji but it doesn't insert into my database.

While writing this, I noticed that adding `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'` stops the whole process from working but I'm not sure why.

Backend Code for those that asked:

```
<?php
$host = "hostname";
$user = "user";
$password = "pass";
$db_name = "database";
$tbl_name = "table";

// Connect to server and select databse.
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password)or die("cannot connect");
mysqli_select_db($conn, $db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $detail = $_POST['detail'];

    // Add your validation and save data to database
    if(strlen($detail) <= 5000) {
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

        $sql = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET detail = ?";
        if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $detail);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
}
?>
```

**NOTE**: This works when I pass it through a form but via AJAX when adding an emoji such as  it doesn't work.

Comment: For the insert we'd need to see the PHP code. My guess is `$detail` isn't what you expect it to be. The content type your are stating is the default for jQuery AJAX, so if there are no errors in the console, this is going to be hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: It would be good also to see HTTP request from debugger in browser.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I edited my post so you can see the backend. No errors appear in console. `$detail` appears exactly how it's supposed to be and the whole thing works fine until I set `contentType`.

Comment: You do know your update statement is going to populate every row in the table, right?

Comment: Yes I've only got one in there for testing purpose.

Comment: Show us what is in `$detail` and how you set it. Remove content type and set datatype to 'text'

Comment: No detail isn't a PHP variable. When I learned how to use AJAX I've always used $ to declare a variable to pass into data.

Comment: Side note: You realize that you're updating your entire database without a `WHERE` clause, right?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54042223/ajax-post-with-utf-8?noredirect=1#comment94920178_54042223

Comment: Yes I already mentioned that @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Are you trying to insert an emoji?

Comment: Yes, when I add text without an emoji it works fine. When I add an emoji such as , it doesn't process.

Comment: I'd try and add UTF-8 to the connection. Also, emoji requires the column type to be a BLOB.

Comment: I've already done that and it doesn't require it to be a blob as when I submit the data via a form and not ajax it works fine.

Comment: You know that MySQL's default UTF8 isn't actual UTF8, right? If you want to store emoji you need to use utfmb4 for full UTF8 support.

Comment: Yes all my columns are utf8mb4.

Comment: Last ditch effort; check the file(s) encoding. They should all be UTF-8. Note that UTF-8 encoding has a few; with and without BOM (byte order mark). The connection too as I mentioned earlier; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/

Answer (score 0):

Add `mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8mb4');` to all php files after connecting to database.

Comment: I said that; twice.

Comment: Sorry I misread what you were trying to say, answer the question and I will upvote it for you :)

Comment: It was a duplicate which I suspected from the start, but voted otherwise. Thanks anyway.